# Delphi 7 - TDBGrid style

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

How to use stylized table in Delphi 7?
For example:

[image]

Comment: Your example is not really a 'style' more a 'customisation'. A way here : http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa031699.htm

Comment: philnext, no. Not only the color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean which you want themed the TDbGrid component, you can use the [`Themed DBGrid runtime replacement`](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/24513) from Jeremy North's and Andreas Hausladen.

Comment: No effect on Delphi 7 and Windows 7.

Comment: Do you add the `TXPManifest` component to your application?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote and tested for you this example on Delphi 7 and Windows 8.1

Use Event **DrawColumnCell** to change color or something else.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  try
    if Column.FieldName = 'FIRST_NAME' then
      DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  finally
    DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
  end;
end;
```

Download full example:
[file](http://www.filedropper.com/tdbgridstyle)