# Changing background for TDBGrid row?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tdbgrid

I want to simulate Explorer themes for TDBGrid selected row (dgRowSelect), instead of that Blueish color. How can I do that?

Here is a sample of the expected result:

[image]

Comment: See `TCustomGrid.DrawCell`.

Comment: Vlad, if you were looking for a completely themed grid, you may look at [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12653038/960757). Anyway, you may find your answer in that recommended unit as well.

Comment: @TLama, The unit there is nice, but it does not draws the selection! only the title and the fixed area. The selection is done in the `HighlightCell` virtual method, which I can override and return false. but the DrawColumnCell is too late! I have no chance to paint the "LVP_LISTITEM" style selection before `WriteText`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OnDrawColumnCell event 
Here's a simple example:

```
procedure TForm4.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if mydataSet.FieldByName('Age').AsInteger > 18 then
    DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clRed;
  DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

When you say "simulate", I'm not clear how you're intending to choose the selected row background color, but the following should draw it in a standard TDBGrid.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.DefaultDrawing := False;
  DBGrid1.Options := DBGrid1.Options + [dgRowSelect];
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawDataCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Grid : TDBGrid;
  BackColor : TColor;
begin
  Grid := Sender as TDBGrid;
  if gdSelected in State then begin
    BackColor := clYellow;  // or whatever
    Grid.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackColor;
    Grid.Canvas.Font.Color := Grid.Font.Color;
  end;
  Grid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  Grid.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Field.DisplayText);
end;
```

Comment: Something tells me that OP asks more how to draw a themed selection in a way the `LVP_LISTITEM` part in the `LISS_SELECTED` state is rendered (when themes are enabled). But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @TLama:  Yes, but I was thinking "simulating" meant "like themes, but not actually using them".  But maybe I'm wrong, too!

Comment: @TLama, you are corrent.

Comment: But your code is this very close to what I need becouse here I have the Rect and the Canvas. Except I would rather not force DefaultDrawing := False. let me work this out a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Change the "SelectedBackColor" of the TDBGrid to the color you want.